# Decimal degrees in Main Project Map but not in Print Layout Grid

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layouts

My main map is in decimal degrees (ex. 122.0610 and 6.9119), but when I try to have a Print Layout, the Grid units are different (ex. 396000.00 and 764600.00). I want to maintain the same grid units with the main map as with the print layout.

[image]

I'm using QGIS 2.22.

Comment: Step 1 change to QGis 3, then look at the projection that is set for the grid

Comment: Add screenshots of the projection of the print layout and grid to your question.